# Unable to run yarn during hadoop installation

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am installing HDFS on my local Windows machine. The installayion guide I am following is **https://github.com/MuhammadBilalYar/Hadoop-On-Window/wiki/Step-by-step-Hadoop-2.8.0-installation-on-Window-10**

I was able to follow all the steps mentioned in the above guide. However, in the final step when I run "start-all.cmd" in sbin directory, the yarn nodemanager and resourcemanger fail to execute with the following error **Couldn't find a package.json file in "C:\hadoop-3.0.3\hadoop-3.0.3\sbin"**.

Please find below the screenshot

[image]

Any suggestions on how to get around with this?

Comment: You followed a guide to install Hadoop 2.8, so why are you expecting `3.0.3` to work when that version is a breaking change release?

Comment: I tried installing the 2.8.0 version but facing the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hadoop doesn't care about a package.json file, so that's the first sign something is off with your system.

You've installed `yarn` the **NPM** package manager, which directly conflicts with Hadoop's `yarn` command

You can edit your system PATH to make Hadoop be before the NPM libraries, but then you're going to break your Nodejs development process

Answer (score 7):

You also can modify the start-yarn.cmd , change yarn command path like this:

`start "Apache Hadoop Distribution" %HADOOP_BIN_PATH%\yarn resourcemanager`

`start "Apache Hadoop Distribution" %HADOOP_BIN_PATH%\yarn nodemanager`

Answer (score 0):

Package.json has no role playing in hadoop... So first uninstall Yarn by npm uninstall -g yarn . And then check the yarn version it will show yarn(Hadoop) ...And this is the indication that hadoop  yarn is working